# returning None instead of print statement after conditional

Tags: python-3.x

everything seems to be working properly except i still get the None output when i Run the program and the number is not prime. The 'IS PRIME' works fine without the None value printing

```
def is_prime():

        your_guess = int(input("Choose a number to find out if it's prime..."))

        div = 2
        is_prime = True

        while div < your_guess:
            if your_guess % div == 0:
                is_prime = False
                print ("The Number is not Prime")
                break

            div += 1
        else:
            if is_prime == True:
                return ("The number  is Prime!")

print (is_prime())
```

Comment: `print` and `return` are different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime():
your_guess = int(input("Choose a number to find out if it's prime..."))

div = 2
is_prime = True

while div < your_guess:
    if your_guess % div == 0:
        is_prime = False
        print ("The Number is not Prime")
        break

    div += 1
else:
    if is_prime == True:
        print ("The number  is Prime!")
return is_prime
```

Try this and check the logic of the program. The reason there is a NONE return because you used a return statement after if(is_prime == True). remember return and print are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

A function should return something for both conditions you have specified.

```
def is_prime():
your_guess = int(input("Choose a number to find out if it's prime..."))

div = 2
is_prime = True

while div < your_guess:
    if your_guess % div == 0:
        is_prime = False
        return "The Number is not Prime"
    div += 1
else:
    if is_prime == True:
        return ("The number  is Prime!")


print(is_prime())
```